# How to check in elasticsearch if a JSON object has a key using the DSL?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, dsl

If I have two documents within an index of the following format, I just want to weed out the ones which have an empty JSON instead of my expected key.

A

```
{ 
  "search": { 
      "gold": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

B

```
{
  "search":{}
}
```

I should just get A json and not B json.

I've tried the exists query to search for "gold" but it just checks for non null values and returns the list.
Note: The following doesn't do what I want.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
    "must": [
        { 
           "exists": { "field": "search.gold" }}
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

This is a simple question but I'm unable to find a way to do it even after searching through their docs.
If someone can help me do this it would be really great.

The simplified mapping of the index is :

```
"test": {
    "mappings": {
    "carts": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "_all": {
        "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
        "line_items": {
            "properties": {
            "line_items_dyn_arr": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                "dynamic_key": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you storing complete json in ***search*** field?
If this is not the case then please share the mapping of your index and sample data.

**Update:** Query for nested field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "search",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "search.gold"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For nested type fields we need to specify the ***path*** and ***query*** to be executed on nested fields since nested fields are indexed as child documents.

Elastic documentation: [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

**UPDATE based on the mapping added in question asked:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "line_items.line_items_dyn_arr",
      "query": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "line_items.line_items_dyn_arr"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that we used `"path": "line_items.line_items_dyn_arr"`. The reason we require to provide full path is because `nested` field `line_items_dyn_arr` is itself under line_items object. Had `line_items_dyn_arr` be a property of mapping and not the property of `object` or `nested` field the previous query would work fine.

Comment: By search field what are you exactly meaning? I have not defined any mappings for the index if that is what you are asking. And I think that the json is getting stored in object or nested object format.

I've not given any explicit mappings for the index too.

Comment: To get the mapping of index use: GET  test/_mappings

Comment: I have added query if search is of type nested.

Answer (score 0):

Nishant's answer is right but for some reason I could get it working only if the path and field are the whole paths.

The following works for me.

```
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "search.gold",
        "query": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "search.gold"
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of index? I would like to understand why whole path is required.

Comment: I've added in the question now. If you find out why please let me know.

Comment: `line_items_dyn_arr` is `nested` field and it is under `line_items` which is `object` type which is why to reach till `line_items_dyn_arr` whole path is required.

Comment: Oh ok, so to reach the nested field we have to go till the field path and then use the field name. If you can make the change or add the comment in your answer then I think that would be best for this question. I'll accept your answer itself.